# Undefined method while checking attribute value with Rspec in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am new to ruby, rails and rspec. I want to verify that card numbers have been truncated after they have been saved.

Here is my test code:

```rb
RSpec.describe Payment, type: :model do
  context 'after saving' do  # (almost) plain English
    it 'card number is truncated' do   #
      @payment = Payment.new(
        :card_number => "5520000000000000",
        :card_name => "Tom Jones",
        :card_security_code => "123",
        :card_expiry => "10/30",
        :email => "test@mail.com",
        :address_line1 => "400 Test Lane",
        :state => "WA",
        :postcode => "6000",
        :country => "Australia",
        :status => "processing"
      ).save(validate: false)
      expect(@payment.card_number).to eq('0000')
    end
  end
end
```

Which gives me the error:

```
undefined method `card_number' for true:TrueClass
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the result of `#save` to `@payment`:

```
@payment = Payment.new(...).save(validate: false)
```

So do it in two steps:

```
@payment = Payment.new(
  :card_number => "5520000000000000",
  :card_name => "Tom Jones",
  :card_security_code => "123",
  :card_expiry => "10/30",
  :email => "test@mail.com",
  :address_line1 => "400 Test Lane",
  :state => "WA",
  :postcode => "6000",
  :country => "Australia",
  :status => "processing"
)
@payment.save(validate: false)
```